# Gson attribute name for collection

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this Entity

```
class Foo
{
   public String FooName;
   public String FooId;
}
```

I get an array of `Foo` from a method and I serialize it to json string like this

```
Foo[] foos = getFoos();
String json = gson.toJson(foos, Foo[].class);
```

This generates

```
[
    {
       "FooName" : "FirstFoo",
       "FooId" : "1"
    },
    {
       "FooName" : "SecondFoo",
       "FooId" : "2"
    }
]
```

which is fine except I have a requirement to have a wrapper attribute like this

```
{
  "foos":[
            {
               "FooName" : "FirstFoo",
               "FooId" : "1"
            },
            {
               "FooName" : "SecondFoo",
               "FooId" : "2"
            }
         ]
}
```

I know I can create a wrapper class

```
class Foos
{
    Foo[] foos;
}
```

and use Foos.class with gson but I have 100s of classes like `Foo` and I would hate to create a wrapper class for each. I was also thinking about just doing some string manipulation to the original json returned to add the wrapper attribut but I'm keeping that for plan B (or even C). 
So, I was wondering if there is a way in gson to add a wrapper attribute like what I'm asking above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a manual way to do this:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Foo[] foos = new Foo[] {};

final JsonElement elem = gson.toJsonTree(foos);
final JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj.add("foo", elem);
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();          
obj.add("foos", gson.toJsonTree(foos, Foo[].class));            
String json = obj.toString();
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `toJsonTree`. My bad.